# A problem in additive number theory.

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

**Original Problem:** Counterexample given below by user francis-jamet.

Let $A\subset \mathbb Z_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If $A-A=\mathbb Z_n$, then $0\in A+A+A$

---

**New Problem:** 
Is the following statement true? If not, please give a counterexample.

If $A-A=\mathbb Z_n$ and $0\not\in A+A$, then $0\in A+A+A$.

Comment: A small observation: if the statement is true, then $A+A+A$ also contains all multiples of three.

Comment: There are no counterexamples for $n \leq 16$. [Link](http://hpaste.org/70534) to a very naive Haskell program

Comment: All tests pass $A - A = {\mathbb Z}_n \implies A + A + A = {\mathbb Z}_n$. The stronger conclusion $A + A = \mathbb {\mathbb Z}_n$ is false: $n=6$ and $A=\{1,2,4\}$.

Comment: @sdcvvc Ha! No wonder I had a hard time proving it. (The false result I mean.)

Comment: No counterexamples for $n \leq 23$ (if there is no bug in my program).

Comment: I've restored the original problem to go side by side with new problem. I think it is less confusing for readers this way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the original problem, there is a counterexample for $n=24$ and $A=\{3,9,11,15,20,21,23\}$.

There are no counterexamples for $n \leq 23$.

For the new problem, there is a counterexample:

$n=29$ and $A=\{4,5,6,9,13,22,28\}$.

There are no counterexamples for $n \leq 28$.

Comment: A test in Python (it gives "True"): a=[3,9,11,15,20,21,23]; set([(x-y+24) % 24 for x in a for y in a])==set(range(24))

Comment: Oh, and the following expression evaluates to False: 0 in set([(x+y+z) % 24 for x in a for y in a for z in a])

Comment: Thanks very much for the counterexample!!

Comment: @TerryZhou:  So as not to undermine francis-jamet's efforts in solving your original problem, I think it would make more sense to start a new question and include a link to this one.

Comment: @CamMcLeman I apologize for modifying the question straight.

Comment: @TerryZhou: No need to apologize.  There are some subtleties to the system (both technologically and socially) that take some adapt to.

Comment: I just finished writing a program to search for counterexamples to both problems as francis updated this. So I'll just leave my results as a comment. I found another counterexample to the original problem [1,3,4,9,13,15,21]. And to the second problem I found [1,7,16,20,23,24,25].

Comment: Sorry, both are the same as francis-jamet. 24 and 29, respectively.

Comment: @Jacob: Your examples are negated versions of francis's sets.

Comment: @sdcvvc Interesting, as it turns out there are only two other counterexamples for n=29. [2, 3, 11, 14, 17, 19, 21] and it's negation along with the other two francis and I have already listed.